# How to display partial TOC (only one section at a time)?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

I already know how to print an Outline with only the current section. What I'd like to do is to have an Outline slide with some extra info (for instance, a publication) below each section of TOC. I already tried doing it "by hand", but can't get the same formatting/style/bullets as in TOC.

Example:

Section 1

- extra info for section 1 not related to TOC

Section 2

- extra info for section 2 not related to TOC

A minimum working example follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
}

\AtBeginSection[] {
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    I'd Like something like this (but with the same formating as the next frame):
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Section A
        \only<1>{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item some additional info about A
            \end{itemize}
        }
        \pause
        \item Section B
        \only<2>{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item some additional info about B
            \end{itemize}
        }
        \pause
        \item Section C
        \only<3>{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item some additional info about C
            \end{itemize}
        }
        \pause
        \item Section D
        \only<4>{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item some additional info about D
            \end{itemize}
        }
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents[pausesections,hideothersubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{Section A}

\subsection{Subsection A.1}

\begin{frame}
    Test A.1
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection A.2}

\begin{frame}
    Test A.2
\end{frame}


\section{Section B}

\subsection{Subsection B.1}

\begin{frame}
    Test B.1
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection B.2}

\begin{frame}
    Test B.2
\end{frame}


\section{Section C}

\subsection{Subsection C.1}

\begin{frame}
    Test C.1
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection C.2}

\begin{frame}
    Test C.2
\end{frame}


\section{Section D}

\subsection{Subsection D.1}

\begin{frame}
    Test D.1
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection D.2}

\begin{frame}
    Test D.2
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually there is an example of this in the `beamer` manual.

Comment: Could you point me out the example in the beamer manual? (page or section)

Comment: If you add a fake `subsubsection` and use that as the info, then you should be able to accomplish what you want, of course you have problems with different levels in different parts. But I think that is the easier thing.

Comment: What if the extra info is a series of items and several references to published work? Can I still use a fake subsection?

Comment: Hmm, that will probably be much more difficult.